# MessageDocNotDisclosedError shown in LiveCycle HTML Workspace ES4 with IE

Tags: livecycle

I have an Adobe LiveCycle process that flattens a PDF form and displays the result to users in LiveCycle HTML Workspace ES4. The flattened form appears fine in Firefox and Chrome browsers however when viewing the same form in Microsoft Internet Explorer a "Message from webpage" window is prompted with this message: "MessageDocNotDisclosedError: Target document not disclosed."

The flattened form appears fine in IE and the application still works however I would prefer to get rid of this prompted error message. Is there a way to avoid this error message in IE?

I have seen this error message with flattened documents in the following environments:

Windows 7 / Internet Explorer 9 / Adobe Reader 11 add-on

Windows 7 / Internet Explorer 11 / Adobe Acrobat Pro 11 add-on

Answer (score 0):

How are you returning your flat PDF? Are you flattening the PDF as part of the LiveCycle application and using a document variable, or are you using a custom render process? Also is the PDF document still opened through your Reader/Acrobat plugin in Firefox and Chrome?

Sounds like you have a Forms Bridge issue. When using a render process (Configurable from your Action Profile on the Assign Task activity or from the XDP template in Workbench) the default render process will inject JavaScript inside the PDF to communicate with the Workspace frame. If you're not injecting this script, the PDF and frame won't be able to communicate. If this is the case, the best way to fix this would be to:

1. Copy the **Process Management (System)\Render PDF Form** process into your application
2. Edit the process to return a flattened PDF instead of a dynamic one
3. Edit you form's action profile to use the new render process.

Answer (score 0):

My team was able to get rid of the "MessageDocNotDisclosedError" message in Internet Explorer by reverting back to an earlier build of LiveCycle HTML Workspace. We reverted back from version 1.1.30 to version 1.1.14 and now the message no longer appears.